# Автозаполнение инпута

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список `mas`. Есть пользовательский ввод.

Как сделать так, чтобы при наборе символов пользователем, выпадало окно с вариантами из списка `mas`, содержащими символы, которые ввел пользователь?

То что я ищу очень похоже на автозаполнение в PyCharm, например. Пользователь начинает вводить и список начинает ссужаться, при этом пользователь должен видеть варианты и иметь возможность выбрать какой-либо до того как закончит набирать текст и желательно, чтобы это все извращение происходило в консоли.

Comment: Это в какой библиотеке? Tkinter, pyqt4, pyqt5, flask, diango, ...?

Comment: Если речь про консоль, то ничего кроме curses/npyscreen + msvcrt.getche() в голову не приходит.